# calendaerView selecting a junary date crashes app

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, calendarview

I am creating an Xamarin app utilizing the CalendarView. When selecting a date everything is fine EXCEPT for a January date. Any date in any year in the month of January my app crashes and I get 'The app has unexpectely stoppped working'.

My XML code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <CalendarView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cdrCalendar"
        android:maxDate="01/01/2026" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My C# code is

```
namespace BitesBoardMobile.Droid
{
    class dialog_calendar : DialogFragment
    {
        private CalendarView _calendar;
        private TextView _text;
        private int _month;
        private int _year;
        private int _day;

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

            var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.dialog_calendar, container, false);

            _calendar = view.FindViewById<CalendarView>(Resource.Id.cdrCalendar);
            _text = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);

            _calendar.DateChange += (object sender, CalendarView.DateChangeEventArgs args) =>
            {
                var newdate = new DateTime(args.Year, args.Month, args.DayOfMonth);
                _month = newdate.Month + 1;
                _year = newdate.Year;
                _day = newdate.Day;
                _text.Text = _year + "/" + _month + "/" + _day;
            };

            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

all I am doing so far is just getting the selected date and putting it in the TextView.

Are they any ideas out there?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener.html

> month int: The month that was set [0-11].

This means January is 0. But the `DateTime` constructor needs 1 for January. So you have to add one, like you did one line below.

```
_calendar.DateChange += (object sender, CalendarView.DateChangeEventArgs args) =>
{
    var newdate = new DateTime(args.Year, args.Month + 1, args.DayOfMonth);
    _text.Text = newdate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike many things in .NET, the [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) constructor expects it's arguments to be 1 based, not 0 based.  If the Android arguments are 0 based, you will need to add 1 to them.